# RollingFileAppender to create a log file

Tags: log4j, rollingfileappender

Following is my Log4J.xml file, Basically I am trying to use the RollingFileAppender to create a file which will be rolled over on daily basis.

I have necessary jar files in lib folder and using Tomcat 7.0 to run the application but when the server starts it gives following message.

log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 13 and column 13
log4j:WARN The content of element type "appender" must match "(errorHandler?,param*,rollingPolicy?,triggeringPolicy?,connectionSource?,layout?,filter*,appender-ref*)".

Any idea what could be wrong with following code?

-

```
<logger name="com.vzw.issi.logger.util.AlertManager" additivity="false">
    <level value="ERROR"/>
    <appender-ref ref="email"/>
</logger>

<!-- RULES for logging DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR < FATAL -->
<root>
    <priority value="INFO"/>
    <!-- <priority value="SYS_DATA" class="com.vzw.issi.logger.util.SystemDataLoggerLevel" /> -->  
    <appender-ref ref="vEliteLog"/>
    <appender-ref ref="stdout"/> 
</root>
```

Comment: is that all? where do you define the maxfile size?  the roll over times, etc.?

Comment: Sorry actually when I was trying to paste the code in editor it was not getting in, I do not know why :(